# How may i run an application and pass parameters to it through c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to run an external application and pass some parameters to it.

How may i do this in .net framework?

Comment: Have you ever look at [`Process` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process) and it's properties?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try it with the `Process` class:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "<Folder>/<filename>.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "your Parameters";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
int code = process.ExitCode;
```